# Python, Mechanize - print link.text if text does not contain [IMG]

Tags: python, mechanize

I have a Python program that prints out links from certain site. It looks like this:

```
import urllib
import re
import mechanize
import urlparse

url = "http://sparkbrowser.com"

#Mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
br.open(url)


for link in br.links():
newurl = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
b1 = urlparse.urlparse(newurl).hostname
b2 = urlparse.urlparse(newurl).path
wholeLink = "http://"+b1+b2
    linkTxt = link.text
    print wholeLink
    print linkTxt
```

which gives me output like that(I've shorten a result for this purpose):

```
http://twitter.com/sparkbrowser
Twitter[IMG]
http://facebook.com/sparkbrowser
Facebook[IMG]
http://www.flickr.com/photos/sparkbrowser
Flickr[IMG]
http://youtube.com/sparkbrowser
Youtube[IMG]
http://vimeo.com/user7123627
Vimeo[IMG]
http://plus.google.com/103169821052890438536
Google[IMG]
http://sparkbrowser.com/index.php
Home
http://sparkbrowser.com/download.php
Download
http://sparkbrowser.com/about.php
About
```

How can I exclude those results which contains `[IMG]` in text?

I've tried something with `regex` and `.search()` but I failed. I need something like if `link.text != ('*[IMG]')` print it out but I don't know how to implement it correctly...

Any advice is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in` operator.

```
...
for link in br.links():
    newurl = urlparse.urljoin(link.base_url, link.url)
    b1 = urlparse.urlparse(newurl).hostname
    b2 = urlparse.urlparse(newurl).path
    wholeLink = "http://"+b1+b2
    linkTxt = link.text
    if '[IMG]' in linkTxt:
        continue
    print wholeLink
    print linkTxt
```

Or, `not in`

```
...
for link in br.links():
    ...
    if '[IMG]' not in linkTxt:
        print wholeLink
        print linkTxt
```

### Example interactive shell session

```
>>> '[IMG]' in 'Stackoverflow [IMG]'
True
>>> '[IMG]' not in 'Stackoverflow [IMG]'
False
>>> '[IMG]' in 'Stackoverflow'
False
>>> '[IMG]' not in 'Stackoverflow'
True
```

See [Sequence Types — str, unicode, ...](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

Comment: it's that easy? I could not believe it... thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

It's better to filter links by passing `text_regex` argument to `br.links()`:

```
for link in br.links(text_regex=re.compile('^((?!IMG).)*$'))
```

`'^((?!IMG).)*$'` matches all link texts that don't contain `IMG` in it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Love this stuff with regex use to... but for now @falsetru answer is easier to me, but will use your solution for sure... Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, it's easier to use `in`, but it will result into more looping steps because `br.links()` will return more than you actually need.

Comment: I suppose that your example is more efficient for large work, and I like that, because in future I will use it for sure... Momentaly I'm scraping noobie ho shows that code to even larger noobies, so will use lighter example :)